# PHP validation if not exists price

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two inputs Price1 and Price2. And if I have only one price what I add to Price1 and Price2 will be empty. So I want it add to Database and in database in price 2 doesnt have

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST["submitmenu"])){
$menu_item_category  = $_POST["menu_item_category"];
$menu_item_name      = $_POST["menu_item_name"];
$menu_item_details   = $_POST["menu_item_details"];
$menu_price1         = $_POST["menu_price1"];
$menu_price2         = $_POST["menu_price2"];

$query_orders = "INSERT INTO menus (menu_item_category,menu_item_name,menu_item_details, menu_price1, menu_price2) 
VALUES ('$menu_item_category','$menu_item_name','$menu_item_details', '$menu_price1', '$menu_price2');";
mysqli_query($con, $query_orders);
}
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menus` (
  `menu_item_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `menu_item_category` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `menu_item_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `menu_item_details` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `menu_price1` double NOT NULL,
  `menu_price2` double NOT NULL,
  `menu_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`menu_item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=244 ;
```

Its working only when I add 2 prices.

> EXAMPLE:
>
> Price1 = 20
>
> Price2 = 30

Then its working and sending database.
But if i dont insert price into Price2 then it not sending database.

> EXAMPLE:
>
> Price1 = 20
>
> Price2

Comment: ALTER your column so it accepts an empty / null value or use a ternary operator to give it 0 value.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Beat me to it, that should be the answer.

Comment: What you mean ALTER?

Comment: ALTER means "to change/modify" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Better to use `DECIMAL()` rather than `double` as a datatype for money values. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your table is set up with the `menu_price2` is `NOT NULL`. Either alter the table to allow NULL or try something like

```
$menu_price2 = empty($_POST["menu_price2"]) ? $_POST["menu_price2"] : 0;
```

Comment: *"@Fred-ii- Beat me to it, that should be the answer. – ToothlessRebel 3 mins ago"* - You meant "comment" ;-)

Comment: btw, best to use `empty()` rather than `isset()`.

Comment: Nah, meant your comment should be written as a full answer since it's accurate.

Comment: It's all yours ;-)